# Different behavior of MSVC and clang for if constexpr branches

Tags: c++

Given this helper function:

```
template<typename Type>
std::string toString(Type const& value, bool encloseInQuotes = false) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same<bool, Type>::value) {
    auto s = value ? "true" : "false";
    return encloseInQuotes ? "\""s + s + "\"" : s;
  }

  if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value) {
    if (std::isnan(value)) {
      return encloseInQuotes ? "\"NaN\"" : "NaN";
    }
  }

  return "";
}
```

which is supposed to convert basic types (and strings) to a string expression, I get a compilation error with MSVC when using it like this:

```
int main() {
  std::string temp = toString(true);
  return 0;
}
```

With clang this compiles without any problem, with MSVC however I get this:

> 2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(403): error C2668: 'fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function
>
> 2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(288): note: could be 'int fpclassify(long double) noexcept'
>
> 2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(283): note: or       'int fpclassify(double) noexcept'
>
> 2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(278): note: or       'int fpclassify(float) noexcept'
>
> 2>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\math.h(403): note: while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty)'
>
> 2>        with
>
> 2>        [
>
> 2>            _Ty=int
>
> 2>        ]
>
> 2>: note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan(_Ty) noexcept' being compiled
>
> 2>        with
>
> 2>        [
>
> 2>            Type=int,
>
> 2>            _Ty=int
>
> 2>        ]

Obviously the compiler considers the `if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value)` test as valid alternative too and generates the mentioned error. However, at runtime it correctly takes the path for bool (when I leave out the `if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value)` part or use a cast `if (std::isnan(static_cast<double>(value)))`).

How can I make this compile correctly on Windows as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `bool` at least two type traits return `true`:

```
std::is_same<bool, Type>::value
std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value
```

and then you make a call `std::isnan(true)`. Use `else if`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<bool, Type>::value) {
    auto s = value ? "true" : "false";
    return encloseInQuotes ? "\""s + s + "\"" : s;
}
else if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value) {
    if (std::isnan(value)) {
        return encloseInQuotes ? "\"NaN\"" : "NaN";
    }
    ...
}
else
    return "";
```

Comment: This solution won't work, for example, in case `Type` is deduced as `int`. It will trigger the very same error: https://godbolt.org/z/u4e0HF.

Comment: That's the fault of OPs original code. What if its an `int` and not `nan`? It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @SombreroChicken It's kind of weird, since according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan, there should be an overload for integral types, that should behave the same as the overload for `double`. Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/qcTfQs.

Comment: @DanielLangr, then you should put another `if constexpr` before trying to invoke `isnan`.

Comment: @DanielLangr, the absence of that overload is probably a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @SombreroChicken, it's not a fault, it is a consequence of a reduction to a minimal example. Original code was perfectly fine in this respect.

Comment: @Evg My point is, that the problem is primarily caused by a bug in MSVC implementation (missing overload of `std::isnan` and `std::isinf` for integral types) and not by a missing `else`, as your answer suggests.

Comment: That's what I think now too.

Comment: @DanielLangr, this is true for this *particular* problem. But what if `isnan` didn't have an overload for integral type? Then you have to use `else if`s to exclude that branch. So I think this answer is still relevant to the question, because someone else might find this question trying to solve a similar problem but not exactly the same one.

Comment: @Evg If you need, in a branch, to call a function intended for floating-point arguments only, wouldn't a much better solution be to simply use `if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<Type>)`? There is no need for `else if` then.

Comment: @Evg If you check for an arithmetic type and then call a function that is not valid for all arithmetic types, that's wrong design. That has nothing to do with the presence/absence of `else`. BTW, I didn't say you question wasn't relevant. I think it is.

Comment: @DanielLangr, my aim was to demonstrate another point: you can use `else if` to exclude a branch if you have to. In this particular case you can redesign the code to get even better solution. I totally agree with that.

Answer (score 7):

`std::isnan` and `std::isinf` seemingly internally calls `fpclassify` in MSVC. This function is overloaded for floating-point types, and you pass an argument of type `bool`, thus the call is *ambiguous*.

To avoid this, you may cast the arguments, e.g., to `double`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic<Type>::value) {
  if (std::isinf((double)value)) {
    return encloseInQuotes ? "\"INF\"" : "INF";
  }

  if (std::isnan((double)value)) {
    return encloseInQuotes ? "\"NaN\"" : "NaN";
  }
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/W7Z3r3

---

**UPDATE**

This seems to be a bug in MSVC implementation, since, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf), there should be an overload for integral arguments that behaves the same as the `double` overload. Minimal example:

```
auto b = std::isnan(1);
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/qcTfQs

Comment: That's what I did in an attempt to solve the problem, but that shouldn't be necessary at all, since the bool branch is taken anyway for bool input. Why does MSVC even make the input type an `int`? That seems to be kinda compiler gotcha to me.

Comment: @MikeLischke but that's the problem - both branches were getting called, because you didn't have an else, and a bool is both an arithmetic type, and same as bool (obviously). So both if's were true.

Comment: @Steve And is it a problem to have multiple `if constexpr` with a true-evaluated condition?

Comment: OK, I see. It's a bit difficult to check this fully as clang doesn't produce a warning or error for bool values when used with `std::isnan` or `std::isinf`. Hence I cannot say for sure if clang optimizes this out when it compiles a return in the bool branch.

Comment: @MikeLischke Why should it produce a warning? `bool` is an integral type, therefore it simply uses the overload for integral arguments, which is correct behavior.

Comment: @MikeLischke, it is not a question of optimization. If clang didn't have an overload for integral types, you'd get the same error. Even if the function is not called at runtime, the compiler has to be able to generate a call.